# Get request details from GRPC

Tags: go, grpc

For normal HTTP requests, I can get details like the protocol, remote IP, host, method, request URL, referrer, user agent, etc. I know I can extract metadata associated with the request by doing this:

```
var extracted string

meta, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
if ok {
    if value, ok := meta[header]; ok && len(value) > 0 {
         extracted = value[0]
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I understand that HTTP headers will be inserted into the metadata, but that only applies for requests made via the HTTP gateway so requests made from a GRPC client wouldn't necessarily include this information.

But I'm not sure which values to use for `header` or if this information would be available in the metadata at all, or if I should check somewhere else. How can I get this request-related information from a GRPC request?

Comment: You can not get the request-related information through `meta[header]`? any details could  you give ?

Comment: I can, but I'm trying to get the specific headers listed for logging purposes and I'm not sure whether that information is included in the metadata or if there's something else I have to do.

Comment: The MD is `type MD map[string][]string` you could try to iterate the map MD, namely the `meta` from `metadata.FromIncomingContext`.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see the inner type. But is there a guarantee of which headers are present? I don't see this information anywhere.

Comment: IMO, the MD includes all headers...

Comment: Interesting. So I can treat it just the same as `Headers` on the normal HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, you could treat MD as treat same as Headers

Comment: Just update my answer and add one more doc, hope it could help you

Comment: @zangw Thanks, this really did. I wasn't able to find any documentation for this anywhere so I really appreciate the confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per doc [Metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md), in order to read the head from the metadata through `Get` after `metadata.FromIncomingContext`. And since the `MD` is `type MD map[string][]string` you could try to iterate the map `MD` and treat it as same as `Headers` of HTTP request.

**Note**: all the keys will be automatically converted to **lowercase**

Doc [gRPC over http2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md)

> Request-Headers are delivered as HTTP2 headers in HEADERS + CONTINUATION frames.

> Request-Headers → Call-Definition *Custom-Metadata

> HTTP2 requires that reserved headers, ones starting with ":" appear before all other headers. Additionally implementations should send Timeout immediately after the reserved headers and they should send the Call-Definition headers before sending Custom-Metadata.

Sample codes

```golang
import "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"

func (s Server) Method(ctx context.Context, *Request) (*Response, error) {
  var values []string

  md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
  for key, val := range md {
     // get key and val of headers
  }
  
}
```